# Dictionary with user input

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get my program to print a grade with the name the user enters but whenever I run my code it comes back backward. What am I doing wrong?

```python
StudentGrades={'Ava': 'A', 'Brandon': 'B', 'Todd': 'C'}

while True:
    print('Enter a name: ')
    name = input()
    if name in StudentGrades:
        print(StudentGrades[name] + ' recieved the grade ' + name)
```

Comment: It's important to tag your question with, at the least, the language in use so it will be seen by the users best able to help you.  Also, I don't know Python but can surmise that `StudentGrades[name]` is the user's grade and `name`, of course, is their name, so you have them transposed.

Answer (score 1):

Just change one line to see it works as you expect:

```py
#  the name is the dict. key

if name in StudentGrades:    # name is the key
   #print(StudentGrades[name] + ' recieved the grade ' + name)
   print(f" {name}'s grade: {StudentGrades[name]} ")

# Example of running it interactively:
Ava
Ava's grade: A
```